# Can I move system gitconfig?

Tags: linux, git, testing, git-config

How can I move system gitconfig from /etc/gitconfig to a writable location for test purpose on linux?

I do some git test on a cloud VM and I don't have root access to create /etc/gitconfig when I run git config --system --e.

Maybe I can built git with a prefix, but I won't be dynamic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a system git config file to do your tests? That seems strange. Maybe you should ask about that.

Comment: I test my application that uses system config to notify all repos for all users. So it does not seem strange to me.

Comment: How about `--global -e` or `--local -e`?

Comment: global is for user, so in my case I will have to write into all users ~/.gitconfig file and maybe I am not allowed to write. And same for local

Comment: @mr70m4 Having tests that rely on altering system files is a bad practice. It means you have to alter the system *before* you know the install works. It means you have to run the tests as root, really bad. This is probably better solved with an override to change the config location for testing purposes rather than having it hard coded, and it will improve flexibility in general. Or put your custom information into your own config file rather than the system git config.

Comment: @Schwern I know it is bad idea to alter file system. But I am doing a git service via JGit and there is this option to do a system config. The first thing JGit does to system configure is to run this command: git config --system --e. I want to use it to block access to all repo via a (j)git config command. So I don't think I am doing a bad practice here, I am using a git functionality.